# Android Admob testmode : No fill. Server replied that no ads are available

Tags: android, admob

I followed the admob SDK tutorial to set up ads for my android application.
But I get no test adds returned :(. Also, on the admob site no requests are registered.
When I run my app the log says the following :

```
03-18 08:23:56.392: INFO/AdMobSDK(1278): Publisher ID set to xxxxxxxx
03-18 08:23:56.392: INFO/AdMobSDK(1278): Making ad request in test mode
03-18 08:23:56.513: INFO/AdMobSDK(1278): No fill.  Server replied that no ads are available (120ms)
```

The xxx is my publisher Id, but I hid it here with x'es :).
I did set my publisher id in the manifest.

I did set the "setTestDevices method" in my code with the device id the logcat requested

```
AdManager.setTestDevices( new String[] { "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", } );
```

What did I do wrong?? I should get test ads on my phone I suppose?

Comment: You can always ask in the googleGroup if you want an official answer: http://groups.google.com/group/google-admob-ads-sdk/

Answer (score 1):

I find AdMob's test mode to be very unreliable. Sometimes I get no ad, sometimes a test ad, and occasionally real ads show.

I'd not worry about it too much, and instead make sure that ads are showing on the live app. you may want to look at Adwhirl if you don't get ads showing. A fill-reate error basically means AdMob didn't sell all the ad space, so if you want ads to always be shown you may need to look beyond AdMob. Adwhirl is an aggregator, owned by AdMob, so it'll pull ads from other networks if they don't have an ad.

Comment: There is an attribute called testing device id in the admob sdk. Why is that required? There is a warning in the admob documentation - "Warning: Make sure you're in test mode during development to avoid being disabled for clicking your own ads. See the Best Practices guide for more details on enabling test ads." How will admobknow that I am clicking my own add?